# subquery must return only one column , how can i fix it

Tags: sql

How many times has any customer whose first name starts with “A” rented movies
in which “JULIA MCQUEEN” (first name Julia) acted? Your solution must use
joins and your output should be a single number.

```
SELECT count(r.rental_id) 
FROM rental r
JOIN customer c on r.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN store s on c.store_id = s.store_id
JOIN inventory i on s.store_id = i.store_id
JOIN film_actor fa on i.film_id = fa.film_id
JOIN actor a on fa.actor_id = a.actor_id

WHERE  a.actor_id = 21 and c.first_name = (select * FROM customer where first_name like 'A%');
```

how can i fix it

Comment: "select firstname..."

Comment: Why shouldn't the filter in the where clause be just WHERE  a.actor_id = 21 and c.first_name like '%A"?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `c.first_name = (select * ...) use` c.first_name = like 'A%'`
2. Use `GROUP BY c.customer_id` also.
3. As per question you should have condition with actor name as `a.first_name = 'Julia'`.

Your complete query will be like below.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, count(r.rental_id) rented_count
FROM rental r
JOIN customer c on r.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN store s on c.store_id = s.store_id
JOIN inventory i on s.store_id = i.store_id
JOIN film_actor fa on i.film_id = fa.film_id
JOIN actor a on fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
WHERE  a.first_name = 'Julia' and c.first_name like 'A%'
GROUP BY c.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting issue because of

- the multiple column selection in `IN` query (*)
- other issue is with `=` which expects one value only (Number of rows).

I think you can totally avoid the `IN` subquery

replace

```
WHERE a.actor_id = 21 
  and c.first_name = (select * FROM customer where first_name like 'A%');
```

With

```
WHERE a.actor_id = 21 
  and c.first_name like 'A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the issue because of the `SELECT *` call in your subquery. Personally I avoid subqueries whenever possible (not to say that they're bad, I just prefer `JOIN`s). I rewrote your query to produce just the count and remove the subquery.

Also, I'm assuming `actor_id = 21` is Julia McQueen's ID, right?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(r.rental_id) [RentedCount]
FROM 
    rental [r]
    JOIN customer [c] on r.customer_id = c.customer_id
        AND c.first_name LIKE ('A%')
    JOIN store [s] on c.store_id = s.store_id
    JOIN inventory [i] on s.store_id = i.store_id
    JOIN film_actor [fa] on i.film_id = fa.film_id
    JOIN actor [a] on fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
        AND a.actor_id = 21
```